# Strange behavior of Logback - empty files

Tags: java, logging, logback

I'm refurbishing old system that used logback, some simple stuff ( 3 appenders, 2 loggers ). Now in next version of system ( or re-implementation as the previous version was stolen with notebook and backup, only config file and binaries were already on robot ), I use the same config file, but all log files stays empty.

Strange thing is that it actually creates correct files and folders by the given patterns, so it definitely do something with the config file. Besides that, loggers and appenders aren't working at all.

I also tried to use various other configuration files I found on examples - not even one worked, so I'm suspicious that there is some collision between used libraries and logback. I tried to google it, but found nothing relevant or working.

Have anyone of you came around ( or hopefully through ) such a problem? Or please point at the wrong line...

Thx in advance...
Kamil

Next code shows initialization:

```
public static final String LOGGER_CONFIG_FILE = "hacs.logger.conf";
public static final String LOGGER_CONFIG_FILE_DEFAULT = "./conf/logconf.xml";

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        File configurationFile = new File(HACSProperties.instance().getProperty(LOGGER_CONFIG_FILE, LOGGER_CONFIG_FILE_DEFAULT));

        if( configurationFile.exists() ){
            LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
        context.reset(); // When this is commented, logback works in some default configuration

            try {
            JoranConfigurator configurator = new JoranConfigurator();
        configurator.setContext(context);

        configurator.doConfigure( LOGGER_CONFIG_FILE_DEFAULT );
        System.out.println("Logger successfully configured..");

        Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("analytics");
        log.info( "Please appear in file" );

            } catch (JoranException je) {
            System.out.println("Error - failed to configure logger. Please check configuration.");
        je.printStackTrace();

                System.exit( 1 );
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("Error - failed to configure logger - configuration file does not exist. Please check configuration.");

            System.exit( 2 );
        }
}
```

Config file itself:

```
<configuration>
    <timestamp key="bySecond" datePattern="dd.MM.yyyy'_T'HH.mm.ss" timeReference="contextBirth" />

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>./logs/HACS_LAST_RUN.log</file>
        <append>false</append>
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE_PER_MINUTE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>./logs/PER_MINUTE/HACS-RUN-${bySecond}.log</file>
        <append>false</append>
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n
        </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level [%file:%line] %msg%n</Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.hibernate" additivity="false">
        <level value="warn" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_PER_MINUTE" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="FILE_ONLY" additivity="false">
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_PER_MINUTE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </logger>

    <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_PER_MINUTE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

List of libraries:

antlr-2.7.7.jar

aopalliance-1.0.jar

asm-3.3.jar

bcprov-jdk15-1.43.jar

cglib-2.2.jar

chronicle.jar

commons-collections-3.2.1.jar

commons-lang-2.5.jar

commons-logging-1.1.1.jar

commons-pool-1.5.2.jar

cxf-2.3.0.jar

cxf-manifest.jar

cxf-xjc-boolean-2.3.0.jar

cxf-xjc-bug671-2.3.0.jar

cxf-xjc-dv-2.3.0.jar

cxf-xjc-ts-2.3.0.jar

dom4j-1.6.1.jar

FastInfoset-1.2.8.jar

felix.jar

geronimo-activation_1.1_spec-1.1.jar

geronimo-annotation_1.0_spec-1.1.1.jar

geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.7.1.jar

geronimo-jaxws_2.2_spec-1.0.jar

geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar

geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec-1.0.jar

geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar

geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec-1.1.3.jar

groovy-all-1.8.5.jar

h2-1.3.154.jar

hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar

hibernate3.jar

javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar

jaxb-api-2.2.1.jar

jaxb-impl-2.2.1.1.jar

jaxb-xjc-2.2.1.1.jar

jettison-1.2.jar

jetty-continuation-7.1.6.v20100715.jar

jetty-http-7.1.6.v20100715.jar

jetty-io-7.1.6.v20100715.jar

jetty-server-7.1.6.v20100715.jar

jetty-util-7.1.6.v20100715.jar

jmdns.jar

jra-1.0-alpha-4.jar

js-1.7R1.jar

jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar

jta-1.1.jar

logback-access-1.0.1.jar

logback-classic-1.0.1.jar

logback-core-1.0.1.jar

neethi-2.0.4.jar

oro-2.0.8.jar

saaj-api-1.3.jar

saaj-impl-1.3.2.jar

serializer-2.7.1.jar

slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar

spring-aop-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar

spring-asm-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar

spring-beans-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar

spring-context-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar

spring-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar

spring-expression-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar

spring-jms-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar

spring-tx-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar

spring-web-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar

stax2-api-3.0.2.jar

velocity-1.6.4.jar

waiter-dns.jar

woodstox-core-asl-4.0.8.jar

wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar

wss4j-1.5.9.jar

xalan-2.7.1.jar

xml-resolver-1.2.jar

xmlbeans-2.4.0.jar

XmlSchema-1.4.7.jar

xmlsec-1.4.3.jar